# architecture for monitoring system using java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, storage, monitoring, tivoli

i want to create a web application with JAVA EE in order to monitor Tivoli Storage Manager which is an entreprise solution for storage management and backup data.So what i want to do exactly is to build service/script/scheduled job/timer to run SQL queries in background from TSM server database and extract the result into another database created locally MYSQL for example. So what is the proper way to do that ?

Thanks for your help in advance,

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to perform scheduled jobs.
Personally I prefer Quartz which has integration with Spring
So if you go this way create a Scheduler service using quartz and have another that will accept and "put" data in your MySql DB.

*The main question is if Tivoli has exposed services that allow collection of the data you need.